# Topological space containing a non-trivial path

Tags: general-topology

Can anybody help me in understanding that what is the difference between a path connected space and a topological space having a non-trivial path?

Comment: A non-trivial path just means a non-constant path, and presumably it would just mean that there are some two distinct points which are connected via a path. A path-connected space means all two points can be connected with a path...

Comment: Thanks sir. It means if X is a space containing a non trivial path, then there exists a continuous function p:[0,1]---> X such that p(0) is not equal to p(1). But does this imply that {p(0)} or {p(1)} is closed?

Comment: If $X=\{0,1\}$ with topology $\tau=\{\emptyset,\{1\},X\}$ then $X$ is path connected but $\{1\}$ is not a closed subset. *EDIT:* oops didn't see the qualifier 'or' - I thought you asked if $\{p(0)\}$ **and** $\{p(1)\}$ are closed. I think a counterexample exists where both are not-closed but I'll have to think a bit more.

Comment: Thanks and please reply if you find an example when both {p(0)} and  {p(1)} are not closed.

Comment: If $\: X = \{0\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.03 in}1/2\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.04 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\} \:$ with topology $\: \tau = \{\{\},\{0\},\{1\},\{0,\hspace{-0.04 in}1\},X\hspace{.02 in}\} \:$ then $X$ is path-connected $\hspace{1.22 in}$ but $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are both not closed. $\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer took me a while to find the path from $0$ to $1$ but that's a good example.

Comment: Thanks, this example works for me

Answer (score 1):

One more example:  the set $[0,1]\cup \{2\}$,  with the topology induced by $\mathbb R$, is not path-connected: there is no path from $2$ to the other points of the set. However, it does contain a nontrivial path, such as $\gamma(t)=t$, $0\le t\le 1 $.

If a set has no nontrivial paths, it is called [totally path-disconnected](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Equivalent_Definition_for_Totally_Pathwise_Disconnected). It is possible to be path-disconnected, but not **totally** so.